# C# - Error while copying content to a stream

Tags: c#, .net, http, xamarin

I've this Form in which there are about 10 fields and maximum of 10 images. I upload them to the server and most of the time it works, but sometimes it return an error `Error while copying content to a stream`.

After that when I restart app and try again, sometime it works and sometime not.

**Code**

```
// Image Path
var path_image_1 = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("image_1");

MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multiContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";

// About 10 Fields like this
multiContent.Add(new StringContent(Email), "email");

// About 10 Images
var image_1 = File.ReadAllBytes(path_image_1);
multiContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(image_1, 0, image_1.Count()), "images", path_image_1);


HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, multiContent);
string serverResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: There are lots of potential errors with the setup described above, none of which can be inferred from `Error while copying content to a stream`. Something could be wrong with the network connectivity, something could be wrong with the listening process on the other end, something could be wrong with however the listening process stores the images, the list goes on.

Comment: thanks, could you share some resources? and also is my code correct?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your environment?  Where and how its hosted, etc, would be helpful in diagnosing the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works sometimes, then retrying it a few times might help.  If you use the [polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly/), you can enclose this code in a block that will catch the exception and [retry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry) a configurable amount of times with a configurable amount of wait inbetween them.

```
var policy = Policy
.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
.Retry(3, onRetry: (exception, retryCount) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine($"retry Count is: {retryCount}");
});

policy.Execute(() => DoStuff());
```

And then your actual logic would be in a separate method:

```
public static void DoStuff()
{

// Image Path
   var path_image_1 = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("image_1");

   MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
   multiContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";

   // About 10 Fields like this
   multiContent.Add(new StringContent(Email), "email");

   // About 10 Images
   var image_1 = File.ReadAllBytes(path_image_1);
   multiContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(image_1, 0, image_1.Count()), "images", path_image_1);


   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
   var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, multiContent);
   string serverResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qcUeG5) is a basic example showing it in action.

Comment: I installed the polly nuget package and pasted your code, but now when I click on Submit Button, it does nothing. Actually, there is a submit button, when clicked the code get executed (send form data to server). After adding `Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>().Retry(3, onRetry: (exception, retryCount) =>{ }`, it don't go through curly brackets.

Comment: My apologies.  I haven't used Polly in a while.  I've updated my answer.  The code block inside the retry is just what you want to have happen before each retry.  You still need to define your logic elsewhere and then execute the policy to kick things off.  Also, I would recommend reading the docs.  This is a very basic example and there is a lot more power and options within the Polly library.

Comment: thanks now working perfectly.. also, just small edit, remove `var` from `var policy.Execute(() => DoStuff());`, as `policy` is already assigned above. thanks again for helping :)

Comment: I'm happy to help!  Thanks for the feedback. I updated the code sample.